# Submit Button Hidden on Reports for adding contact to group

Tags: civireport

On CiviCRM 4.6.7 on Drupal 7, under the report settings, there is an option to add the report results to a group. There is no button present for submitting it.

Upon reviewing the code I see this line

```
 <input style="display: none;"
 name="_qf_ContributionDetail_submit_group" value="" type="submit"
 id="_qf_ContributionDetail_submit_group" class="crm-form-submit">
```

The css has an element style of display: none;

I have overwritten this in my custom CSS style to make it display:block with a width, but the button has no text.

What's going on?

Comment: Hi - can you add a link to a Report on Demo site where this is occuring. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The submit button is hidden because the user does not need to click it. When selecting a group you will be instantly presented with a confirm dialog:

[image]

If this is not working for you, you might be experienceing javascript errors on your website. Try this [troubleshooting guide](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35850.0).

Comment: I followed the troubleshooting guide - this was the offending extension. I disabled it, but an upgrade was also available. Note: this extension was also messing up the new tabbed layout of the report interface.

CiviVolunteer
(org.civicrm.volunteer)
4.5-1.3.2

Comment: If upgrading doesn't solve the problem, you can submit a bug report at https://issues.civicrm.org